# Classifying profunctors between slice categories

Tags: category-theory, profunctors

$\require{AMScd}$[Some time ago](https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/229199-learning.3A-questions/topic/on.20displayed.20categories.20vs.2E.20cats.20over.20C) I asked a very specific question about profunctors
$$\begin{CD} {\cal C}/A @>\mathfrak p>> {\cal C}/B\end{CD}$$
between slice categories of a fixed category $\cal C$. I haven't made much progress. Let me recap all I know.

Unwinding the definition, a $\mathfrak p$ as above consists of a functor
$$\begin{CD} {\cal C}/B @>\mathfrak p>> [({\cal C}/A)^\text{op}, {\sf Set}]\end{CD}$$
which in turn is a functor
$$\begin{CD} {\cal C}/B @>\mathfrak p>> [{\cal C}^\text{op}, {\sf Set}]/yA\end{CD}$$
(because the presheaf category over a slice is a slice over the presheaf representable at the object I was slicing), and since a slice category is a comma object this essentially amounts to a functor $p : {\cal C}/B \times {\cal C}^\text{op} \to {\sf Set}$, plus a cocone to $yA$, i.e. a natural transformation $\delta : p \Rightarrow yA$ with components
$$\begin{CD} \delta_{h, C} : p(h, C) @>>> {\cal C}(C,A)\end{CD}$$
when $h\in {\cal C}/B$ and $C\in \cal C$. This is a particularly concrete expression for a $\mathfrak p$ like above, and I tried for a while to find examples of such functors, then going back to the profunctor $\mathfrak p$ they are equivalent to. I found some, but they are all representable (in the sense of being induced by a *functor* between the slices), and I'm pretty sure there are non-representable examples.

So, the question at this point might be summarised as:

> Is the above characterization of ${\sf Prof}({\cal C}/A, {\cal C}/B)$ useful in order to build *non-representable* examples of profunctors $\mathfrak p : {\cal C}/A \to {\cal C}/B$? How can I find some examples of such profunctors?

Comment: What about $p(f,g)=\{$ all commutative squares in $\mathcal C$ with $f$ on the left and $g$ on the right$\}$? Or something along this line? Do we have any restriction or prototype for $\mathcal C$?

Comment: The case I'm ultimately interested is extremely rigid: $\cal C$ is the free category of a graph $G$. Yet, I'd like to understand something of the general problem first...